# Type tables and software hardcoded values

Tags: database, hardcoded

I have this DB model:

[image: DB model]

(`TEXT` is actually `VARCHAR`)

`entity_group_type` is not modifiable at runtime, but it will be modified in a near future to add more entries, several times, by the development team.

Now I need to retrieve all entries from `entity` that are of a given `entity_group_type`. How should the software handle this kind of queries? Should I hardcode `entity_group_type` `_id`/`name` in the software? If so, why do I even need this table then? And what's better, hardcode `_id` or `name`?

Or is this the wrong way to structure my data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your questions one at a time:

**How should you refer to the entity group in the software?  Hard-code the id, or the name?**

Refer to the entity groups in a way that makes your code the most readable.  So, perhaps you use the name, or perhaps a constant that looks like the name but whose value is the id.  Using a constant can avoid one join when you are looking up entities by group type, but usually this is not much of a concern.

**Why do I even need that table in the DB then?  Is this the wrong way to structure my data?**

This is a perfectly acceptable way to structure your data.  The most correct way depends on what you are doing with the data, but for most applications your structure would be correct.  However, you certainly don't **need** that table in the database--you could instead have a "group_type" field on the entity_group table.  Here are the pros and cons:

Advantages of the current structure:

- Easy to add fields that describe the entity_group_type.  For example, you might want to make some group types only viewable by admin users, or disabled, or whatever.  If this is a possiblity for the future, it pretty much requires this database structure.
- Ability to have your database software enforce referential integrity, meaning the data is kept consistent between the entity_group and entity_group_type tables.

Advantages of adding a group_type field on the entity_group table:

- Possibly a simpler representation in your code.  For exameple, if you use a MVC architecture, having the extra table might require another model object in your code.  That's usually not a problem, and may have advantages, but sometimes simpler is better.
- When you are looking up entities by entity group type, your SQL statements will be slightly simpler, since there will be one less table/join involved.

I think in most cases your current structure comes out ahead, although it does depend of how you use the data.  Unless you had a good reason to structure the data differently, I would stick with your current structure.

Comment: Thank you, very well explained pros and cons :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should definitely store `entity_group_type` in the database, in its own table, as per your design diagram above.  Storing that information in the DB makes it possible to query against that information, which adds flexibility to your design.

Once you have this information in the DB, your question seems to be whether it should be broken out into its own table, or just be stored as column in the `entity_type` table.  I think you should break it out into its own table, with a foreign key constraint from `entity_type` to `entity_group_type`.

- Having `entity_group_type` in its own table allows for group types to be preserved even if all of the entity groups of that type are removed from the DB.
- You can leverage the foreign key to ensure that the `entity_group_type` name is spelled consistently.  Inserted `entity_group`s must satisfy the foreign key constraint, and so would have to either reference an existing `entity_group_type` having a properly spelled name, or insert an `entity_group_type` which will set the proper spelling for that new `entity_group_type`.

Use a synthetic key for your `entity_group_type` table, to reduce painful redundancy in the appearance of `entity_group_type` name appearance. This makes the data model more [DRY](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself), and allows updating the `entity_group_type`'s name  to be a simple update to one table.

As for storing the `entity_group_type` in your application logic, I would suggest storing the name, and looking up the id for the `entity_group_type` when it is needed.  I think that would make the application codebase sowewhat more readable, and I think I've made a compelling argument for why I think this relevant information should have a representation in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Given, that you know the `name` of your `entity_group_type` at runtime, then the correct way to find all `entity_group`s with that `entity_group_type.name`, you would use a join:

```
SELECT entity_group._id, entity_group.name, entity_group_type.name AS groupTypeName
FROM entity_group
JOIN entity_group_type ON entity_group.id_type = entity_group_type._id
WHERE entity_group_type.name = 'someGroupName';
```

This would result in all `entity_group` information for the `given entity_group_type name`.

And yes, this is a good or at least possible way to store that kind of information. Just imagine that eventually the `entity_group_type` gets a new attribute, e.g. `disabled`. Then it is still easily possible to find all `entity_group`s which are (not) in `disabled` types.

Comment: Thanks but I know how to do the query, that's not the question :)

Comment: Then I don't get the question ... The entity_group_type may get more entries but it's useless because you want to always get those `entity_group`s with a specific `id_type` anyway? Still, I'd go with a self-explanatory name so you can change the _id for that name later on.

Comment: I never asked how to make the query in the quesion :) Taking your answer, the question is where/how to store `someGroupName` string. Should I hardcode this in the software? If so, why do I even need that table in the DB then? And what's better to hardcode: the `name` or the `_id`? And if not, how should I approach this situation?